# ¿porque no me imprime del 0 al 10 y del 10 al 0?

Tags: java

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Clase here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
                     public class Clase
            {

         public static void main(String [] args)
        {
         int i = 0; int j = 10;
        while (i < j) { System.out.println(i + " " + j); i++; j--;  }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por la condicion que le has puesto, cuabdo `i = 4, j=6,` a la siguiente vez ya no entra en la condicion por que tanto jcmo i valdran lo mismo.

Comment: 5 es mayor a 5??

Comment: "a la siguiente vez ya no entra"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque tienes una variable que incrementa (`i++`) y otra que disminuye (`j--`) al mismo tiempo, siguiendo la logica seria asi:

```
0-10
1-9
2-8
3-7
4-6
5-5
```

Si te das cuenta llega al `5-5` y en tu condicion esta que `i < j`, por lo cual esto no se cumple `5 < 5`, y solo imprimira hasta el `4-6`, si quieres hacer el mismo ejercicio usando el `while`, entonces simplemente quita el `j--` y agrega a tu `System.out.println` el `j-i`, asi:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  int i = 0; int j = 10;
  while (i < j) { System.out.println(i + " " + (j-i)); i++; }
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `for`.

```
        int j = 10;

        for (int i=0; i <=10 ; i++) { 
             System.out.println( i+ "- "+ (j-i)+"\n");
        }
```

Tu condicion hace que cuando llegue al momento de que $j e $i valen 5 ya ni ese ni los posteriores cumpliran la condicion y por tanto no saldran en el output

Comment: Si bien la logica esta bien, el autor esta usando `java`

Comment: Oops, ahora. Aparcao